# Styles.Render in views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Layout page, which renders a couple of stylesheets with the Style.Render function in MVC4.

However, I want to render some page specific stylesheets on a few views only - what's the best practice to do that? Would you make a new bundle and somehow tell the Layout when to render that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout, define a section for the additional styles:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- other stuff here -->
        @RenderSection("CustomStyles", required: false);
    </head>
    <!-- rest of layout -->
</html>
```

Then in your view:

```
@section CustomStyles {
    @* custom style content here *@
}
```

As the section is not required, you can add the view specific styles to only the pages that need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with `@RenderSection("yourCustomSection")` to do this. If it is not required, then you can do it optional.

```
@RenderSection("MyCustomStyleSection",false)
```

Now you can render your custom style bundle in required views as `@section`